# Why would WebGL run slower between machines if OpenGL shows a slight improvement?

Tags: performance, opengl, webgl

I'm new to OpenGL and interested in using a shader to add a filter to 2D output.

I've been looking at [shadertoy.com](http://shadertoy.com) and was surprised to see a huge performance variation between my two machines - a 2013 MacAir (on battery power) with 1.7ghz core i7 CPU + integrated Intel HD Graphics 5000 & 8gb RAM, and a 2008 iMac 3.06 GHz Intel Core 2 Duo + NVIDIA GeForce 8800 GS, 6gb RAM. The latter performs at <half fps.

The [bmark](http://www.wirple.com/bmark/) stress test results show 1747 vs 1142. But I was hoping that a small windowed WebGL shader would not be a stress test and not significantly degrade on semi-recent PCs, eg dualcore MacIntels with OpenGL 2+ GPUs (I see this period iMac in a LOT of offices I visit).

The config on [doesmybrowsersupportwebgl.com](http://doesmybrowsersupportwebgl.com) are nearly the same for the two machines:

iMac 2008:

[image]

MacAir 2013:
[image]

I've also tried a port of one of the shaders in Processing/Java, with the same worse results for the iMac. I checked the [JOGL](http://jogamp.org/deployment/jogamp-current/jogl-applet-version-napplet.html) Java-OpenGL bindings info and again I can't see a major difference in config between the two PCs.

So it would seem the older CPU/GPU just can't run a small windowed WebGL shader at a decent fps.

However, when I run the desktop-based [Geeks3D FurMark OpenGL 2.1/3.2 GpuTest](http://www.geeks3d.com/gputest/), it results in a slightly better benchmark for the iMac.

Why would WebGL run slower between machines if OpenGL shows a slight improvement? What is it about the iMac setup that makes WebGL run so slow?

Comment: what are the OSes and browser versions?

Comment: Hi, I've added the doesmybrowsersupportwebgl.com results

Comment: Looks like it has a much slower CPU?

Comment: It's definitely older but some of the OpenGL tests run faster, and I wouldn't expect a small windowed WebGL shader to be a serious stress test :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an oversimplification but according to wikipedia the GeForce 8800 (which came out 7 years ago) has [a theoretical maximum throughput of 396 gigaflops](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GeForce_8_Series). Where as the Intel HD Graphics 5000, which is only 1 year old, has [a theoretical maximum throughput of 704 gigaflops](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_HD_and_Iris_Graphics).

That's pretty close to twice as fast for the newer machine and which totally makes sense for Shadertoy examples as those are nearly 100% GPU bound. All of the code you type into a fragment shader is 100% run on the GPU, once per pixel rendered. All the CPU is doing is passing in the time to the shader and calling `gl.drawArrays` for a single quad.

As for why the other benchmark shows the old iMac running slightly faster that's likely because the tests they are using are CPU bound in some way and the CPU is running faster. 3.06 ghz vs 1.7.  I'd try comparing only the *PixMark Volplosion* test and/or the *PixMark Piano* tests. I'd expect those to have similar results with the newer Intel GPU significantly faster than the older NVidia GPU

Comment: Fantastic answer!!! Although it's not the answer I wanted - don't think I can subject people's poor old iMacs to a sustained GPU battering, so using a webGL filter is probably not on the cards for my project :)

Comment: It really depends on the filter. The stuff on Shadertoy is extreme. The number of calculation per pixel on many of those are insane. A more standard filter is probably no problem. Try this for example (http://uglyhack.appspot.com/videofx/)